# Change \Chapter Font size in Lyx/Latex in Koma-Script Report using titlesec / redeclaresectioncommand

Tags: titlesec

I am absolutely new to latex so please dont bite my head off if this question is not.

**Problem**

I am trying to change my \chapter style in a koma-script report in Lyx, meaning that i want to change the font size and the spacing before and after title.

**What I tried**

I tried this using the titlesec package as follows:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}   
\titleformat {\chapter}[display]{\thechapter\bfseries\LARGE}{}{0 pt}{\vspace{-45 mm}}[\vspace{-10mm}]
```

This works fine apart from two problems, the specifications of LARGE, Huge etc. are not exactly accurat and my second problem, which is the bigger part, I loose the number as chapter label.

So I tried the following:

```
\titleformat {\chapter}[display]{\thechapter\bfseries\LARGE}{\thechapter}{0 pt}{\vspace{-45 mm}}[\vspace{-10mm}]
```

Which gives my chapter labels back, but moves them into a random position and does not align them in front of my actual chapter title anymore.

Thanks for any advice how to fix this!

**Edit**

Thanks to the comments I am not trying to use titlesec anymore but I am trying to change font size, afterskip and beforeskip as follows:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=10pt,afterskip=10pt,font={\setkomafont\helvet {20pt}}]{\chapter}
```

Which gives me the error:

> Uncontrolled control sequence.
>   Could anyone tell me how I write this correctly ?

Comment: It would be best if you avoid `titlesec`.

Comment: well I am open for any advice what else to use, or how to do it :)

Comment: Please read about `RedeclareSectionCommand` in the KOMA-manual.

Comment: I do not understand what the desired result is. But may be you want to use `\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=10pt,afterskip=10pt,font=\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont]{chapter}`

Comment: @esdd I bet you have a good candidate as a duplicate at hand?

Comment: @Johannes_B Unfortunaly I did not found a real duplicate of the question (change the font size *and* the space above and below).

Comment: @esdd Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. Each of the classes `scrartcl`, `scrreprt` and `scrbook` provide `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to change the skips before and after sectioning titles or the font settings for the titles and someother settings for the titles.

Example:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-10pt,
  afterskip=10pt,
  font=\fontsize{20}{24}\‌​selectfont
]{chapter}
```

Note that `beforeskip=-10pt` results in a vertical skip of 10pt. The `-` ensures that the first paragraph after the sectionning  command is not indented.

The settings for the `font` option of `\RedeclareSectionCommand` have the same effect as if the would be used as argument of `\setkomafont`: all previous settings for the font element are removed. So

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\mdseries]{chapter}
```

does the same as

```
\setkomafont{chapter}{\mdseries}
```

To add only some settings without removing of the old font features, you can use `\addtokomafont`.